# Why do my thumbs disappear when using google chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-lists

So I made my own portfolio website of my photography - [www.ignasphoto.com](http://www.ignasphoto.com) . Now since I am pretty new to html/css and all that this is one of my first work. However I am experiencing a problem with my thumb list on the main index page when using Google chrome. Sometimes a few or all of the thumbs are not visible when the page is loaded and only apear after refreshing the page. They sometimes disappear after I click on a thumb and then come back to the index page and reappear only after refreshing the page. What did I do wrong?

Comment: tested in chrome all works fine

Comment: it doesn't happen always, but quite often. try surfing between pages for a while, it will happend

Comment: when you face the issue use web-inspector(F12) and see the error console if any 404 error logs there....?

Comment: I think the issue can be caused by an app stoping pop-ups

Comment: disable those things and try again...

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the answer to your question but I noticed when viewing the source of your website that you have in your `<head>` you have a `<script>` used to set the parameters of of your effects.

If you wish to neaten things up a bit you could move that script in to a .js file and then link to it.

So if you created a new file in your root directory called effect.js and cut and pasted everything BETWEEN the `<script>` and `</script>` in to effect.js then you can call it in your head using:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="effect.js"></script>`